# HTML to real JavaScript converter

Tags: javascript, html, code-conversion

I'm looking for a HTML to real JavaScript (online) converter. With 'real' I mean creating all elements and all attributes with JS. There are multiple tools online that convert HTML to JavaScript but use other solutions, e.g.

1. Not `document.write()`
2. Not `element.innerHTML`
3. Not `jQuery.HTML()`

Example:

```
<div id="testid">
    <span class="text" data-attribute="value">Text</span>
</div>
```

To

```
var elmDiv = document.createElement('div');
elmDiv.setAttribute('id', 'testid');
var elmSpan = document.createElement('span');
elmSpan.classList.add('text');
elmSpan.dataset['attribute'] = 'value';
elmSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Text'));
elmDiv.appendChild(elmSpan);
```

Comment: Does it *have* to be based on node.js? If so, you would ideally state this in the question. If not, you should remove the tag (as tags should only be used for *requirements*). -- And does it have to be "online", i.e., a Web app, or is a local solution okay, too? If yes, for which operating system?

Comment: If it's a library I could use it in Node.js, but that's not a requirement. A web-based online converter is sufficient. Removed the tag.

Comment: I assume that JavaScript can just hand the browser an HMTL text string and say "process this into a DOM".  (Do I have that right?)  If so, what would be the value of making JS that creates all the DOM elements one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find anything either so i wrote it myself and put it up on https://github.com/n-a-m-e/convert-html-to-javascript I'm pretty sure I thought of everything but if you can think of anything I missed please don't hesitate to improve upon my work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert HTML to Javascript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function convertHTMLtoJavascript(input,keepWhitespace){
            //This works in all modern browser. If your using IE (which you shouldn't be) switch to a browser that supports html5 templates.
            function loopThroughChildNodes(parent,parentNestLevel){
                var elementCounter = 0;
                var textNodeCounter = 0;
                var parentElement = "element" + parentNestLevel;
                var Nodes = parent.childNodes;
                for(var i = 0, currentNode; (currentNode = Nodes[i]) !== undefined; i++){
                    if (currentNode.nodeType == 1){
                        elementCounter++;
                        var currentNestLevel = parentNestLevel + '_' + elementCounter;
                        var currentElement = "element" + currentNestLevel;
                        createElements += '\n\t' + 'var ' + currentElement + ' = document.createElement("' + currentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() + '");';
                        Array.prototype.slice.call(currentNode.attributes).forEach(function(attribute) {
                            setAttributes += '\n\t' + currentElement + '.setAttribute("' + attribute.name + '","' + attribute.value + '");';
                        });
                        appendChildren += '\n\t' + parentElement +'.appendChild(' + currentElement + ');';
                        loopThroughChildNodes(currentNode,currentNestLevel);
                    }else{
                        if(keepWhitespace===true){
                            var text = currentNode.textContent;
                        }else{
                            var text = currentNode.textContent.trim();
                        }
                        if (text!=""){
                            textNodeCounter++;
                            var currentNestLevel = parentNestLevel + '_' + textNodeCounter;
                            var currentTextNode = "textNode" + currentNestLevel;
                            createTextNodes += '\n\t' + 'var ' + currentTextNode + ' = document.createTextNode("' + text.replace(/"/g,'\\x22') + '");';
                            appendChildren += '\n\t' + parentElement +'.appendChild(' + currentTextNode + ');';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var temp = document.createElement('template');
            var createElements = "";
            var createTextNodes = "";
            var setAttributes = "";
            var appendChildren = "";
            temp.innerHTML = input;
            var documentFragment = temp.content;
            loopThroughChildNodes(documentFragment,"");
            if (createElements!="") createElements = '\n\t' + '//Create Elements' + createElements;
            if (createTextNodes!="") createTextNodes = '\n\t' + '//Create Text Nodes' + createTextNodes;
            if (setAttributes!="") setAttributes = '\n\t' + '//Set Attributes' + setAttributes;
            if (appendChildren!="") appendChildren = '\n\t' + '//Append Children' + appendChildren;
            var output = '//to append the html to an element simply write:';
            output += '\n' + '//appendHTMLto(document.getElementById("parent"));';
            output += '\n\n' + 'function appendHTMLto(element){';
            output += createElements;
            output += createTextNodes;
            output += setAttributes;
            output += appendChildren;
            output += '\n' + '}';
            return output;
        }
        function convert(){
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            var keepWhitespace = document.getElementById("whitespace").checked;
            document.getElementById("output").value = convertHTMLtoJavascript(input,keepWhitespace);
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form{
            font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width:90%;
            padding:30px;
            margin:40px auto;
            background: #FFF;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius:10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
        }
        .inner-wrap{
            padding: 30px;
            background: #F8F8F8;
            border-radius: 6px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        h1{
            background: #2A88AD;
            padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;
            margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            font-size: 30px;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
            box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
            border: 1px solid #257C9E;
        }
        h1 > span{
            display: block;
            margin-top: 2px;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
        label{
            display: block;
            font-size: 13px;
            color: #888;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        textarea{
            resize: vertical;
            -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
            -moz-border-left-colors: none;
            -moz-border-right-colors: none;
            -moz-border-top-colors: none;
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
            border-color: -moz-use-text-color #FFFFFF #FFFFFF -moz-use-text-color;
            border-image: none;
            border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
            border-style: none solid solid none;
            border-width: medium 1px 1px medium;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) inset;
            color: #555555;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 1em;
            line-height: 1.4em;
            padding: 5px 8px;
            transition: background-color 0.2s ease 0s;
            display: block;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            -webkit-border-radius:6px;
            -moz-border-radius:6px;
            border: 2px solid #fff;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
            font-family: "Courier New", "Courier", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Typewriter",monospace;
        }
        textarea:focus {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
            outline-width: 0;
        }
        .section{
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #2A88AD;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .section span {
            background: #2A88AD;
            padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
            -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border: 4px solid #fff;
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-left: -45px;
            color: #fff;
            margin-top: -3px;
        }
        button{
            background: #2A88AD;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            color: #fff;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
            box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
            border: 1px solid #257C9E;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        button:hover{
            background: #2A6881;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
            box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
        }
        .option{
            width: 250px;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #4D4D4D;
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Convert your HTML to Javascript Now!<span>This works in all modern browser. If your using IE (which you shouldn't be) switch to a browser that supports html5 templates.</span></h1>
        <div class="section"><span>1</span>Enter the HTML you wish to convert</div>
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <label>HTML Input <textarea id="input" name="input"></textarea></label>
        </div>
        <button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
        <span class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" id="whitespace">Don't get rid of the whitespace in my HTML
        </span>
        <div class="section"><span>2</span>Copy the Javascript</div>
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <label>Javascript Output <textarea id="output" name="output"></textarea></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Any plans to put this live, make it a library or NodeJS module?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is completely what your after, but it may be useful anyway.

The first few results of Google are:

[AndrewDavidson.com](http://www.andrewdavidson.com/convert-html-to-javascript/%20%22AndrewDavidson.com)

Converts your example to

```
document.write( '<div id=\"testid\">\n' );
document.write( '    <span class=\"text\" data-attribute=\"value\">Text</span>\n' );
document.write( '</div>' );
```

[Accessify.com](http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/)

Generates the same as above. But also can do other things, such as `output as document.write statements wrapped in a function` or `Build up a string variable that you can use later`

Then there's [grunt-html-to-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-html-to-js) - a script that runs on grunt, but as I do not have grunt running on my server, I cannot test it, only go by the description. Which is this:

> This plugin converts a group of html files to JavaScript and assembles them into an vanilla javascript. Note that this plugin does not compile the templates. It simply caches the template source code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are a lot of similar tools like the one mentioned by you, but that's exactly what **I didn't want**. See point 1 from the question, `document.write()`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. I don't know of any that do that. Maybe you could write  one :)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that. Hoped SO had the answer, Google didn't gave me an answer too.